# Accessing records from a JSON and adding or deleting information

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to Javascript, so this is probably fairly easy.

I have this JSON:

```
var collection = {
    2548: {
      album: "Slippery When Wet",
      artist: "Bon Jovi",
      tracks: [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    2468: {
      album: "1999",
      artist: "Prince",
      tracks: [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    1245: {
      artist: "Robert Palmer",
      tracks: [ ]
    },
    5439: {
      album: "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
```

And this function:

```
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks"){
    return collection.id.prop.value;
  } else if (value !== "" && prop === "tracks"){
    return collection.id.prop.push(value);
  } else {
    delete collection.id.prop.value;
  }

  return collection;
}
```

These are my tests:

> updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
>
> updateRecords(2548, "artist", "");
>
> updateRecords(1245, "tracks", "addicted to love");
>
> updateRecords(2458, "tracks", "");

What I need to do is write a function that will access the `JSON` information and add the information if the argument `value` is non-blank (`value !== ""`) and `prop` argument is not `tracks` (`props !== "tracks`) update or set the value for the argument `prop`.

Furthermore if the argument `prop` is tracks (`props === "tracks"`) and the argument `value` is also non-blank (`value !== ""`) I need to push the value onto the end of the `tracks` inside of the `JSON` file.

My question is how could I go about doing this? Mine is obviously failing I understand that I need to `delete` and `push` the information, but accessing the correct data is confusing to me, would I do something like: `return collection.id.prop.push(value);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dot notation to access elements that don't have spaces and bracket notation if they do. Since you don't know if "prop" will contain a space or not here, it's best just to use bracket notation.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Given the following data:

```
// Setup
var collection = {
    2548: {
      album: "Slippery When Wet",
      artist: "Bon Jovi",
      tracks: [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    2468: {
      album: "1999",
      artist: "Prince",
      tracks: [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    1245: {
      artist: "Robert Palmer",
      tracks: [ ]
    },
    5439: {
      album: "ABBA Gold"
    }
};

// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if((value !== "") && (prop !== "tracks")) {
    console.log("Updating or setting property: ", prop);
    console.log("setting property to: ", value);
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  else if((value !== "") && (prop === "tracks")) {
    collection[id].tracks.push(value);
  }
  else if(value === "") {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;
}

updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged: while the original asker might understand, some time in the future someone else may need clarification but the question would be too old to be worth asking.

Comment: The problem isn't space or not, but that `something.prop` is equivalent to `something["prop"]`, and not `something[prop]`.

Comment: Okay so why are the `if/else if`'s in double parenthesis?

Comment: Good question. It makes it easier to read grouping together the if terms. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227248/when-should-you-use-parentheses-inside-an-if-statements-condition

Comment: Refresh page. Had to edit and add it. On a tablet :)

Answer (score 1):

Take care, in your code you used `collection.id.prop.value`. This means it will not resolve variables after the dot, because [`a.b` is equivalent to `a["b"]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

This means you're trying to access a propriety called `id` on `collection`, and so forth.

You should instead use `collections[id][prop].value`.

```
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks"){
    return collection[id][prop].value;
  } else if (value !== "" && prop === "tracks"){
    return collection[id][prop].push(value);
  } else {
    delete collection[id][prop].value;
  }

  return collection;
}
```